# Использование ассоциативного массива

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

Помогите с массивом плииз. Есть таблица `vote_teach`

```
id int(3)
teach int(3)
ocenka int(1)
```

Суть такая. У студентов ведут уроки преподы, их количество может быть 2-3-4-5 итд. 2 раза в год студенты оценивают их. Мне нужно сделать формочку. Нужно выбрать количество преподавателей. (Например, выбирает Цифру 5 - получает 5 выпадающих меню select).
Я могу сделать на фиксированное количество таких форм, без выбора количества. Получается следующий алгоритм. Для каждого препода 2 поля - 1 из бд выводит Фио, 2 - балл. Итого, если я делаю для 3 преподов - 6 полей - 6 переменных, вписываю в бд так:

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('$teach1','$teach1v')");
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('$teach2','$teach2v')");
$result3 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('$teach3','$teach3v')");
```

Где $teach1 - это id препода, $teach1v - оценка препода. Вопрос. Можно ли сделать это в массиве ассоциативном? И как? Типа если я выведу список так:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$count_of_teacher; $i++)
{echo '<select name="teach1">';
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,teach_fam, teach_name FROM teachers");
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
do {
printf ("<option value='%s'>%s %s</option>",$myrow['id'],$myrow["teach_fam"],$myrow["teach_name"]);}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>
echo '</select>';}
```

Вот тут я понял так, что будет 5 выпадающих списков. А как занести их в БД так же в цикле? Как бы в массиве такого вида: **teach [id][оценка]**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Как-то сумбурно вы всё описали... Для начала, я не понимаю, зачем вам нужен выпадающий список преподавателей? Почему не вывести из БД все имена преподавателей и на против каждого поставить выпадающий список с оценками? Во-вторых, вносит сразу несколько записей одним запросом можно так:

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vote ('teacher_id', 't_vote') VALUES ('$teach1','$teach1v'), ('$teach2','$teach2v') , ('$teach3','$teach3v')");
```

В-третьих, для того, чтоб получить массив значений select-ов из формы, записываем так:

```
<select name="teach_vote_array[id_учителя_из_бд]">
    <option value="1">Очень плохо</option>
    <option value="2">Плохо</option>
    <option value="3">Удовлетворительно</option>
    <option value="4">Хорошо</option>
    <option value="5">Отлично</option>
</select>
```

Далее, в обработчике формируем запрос:

```
$teach_vote_array = $_POST['teach_vote_array'];
// формируем запрос
// поля таблицы заменить на свои
$query = "INSERT INTO vote ('teacher_id', 't_vote') VALUES ";
foreach($teach_vote_array as $key => $val){
    $query .= "('$key', '$val'),";
}
// удаляем последнюю лишнюю запятую
$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-1);
// вносим данные в БД
$res = mysql_query($query, $db);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что у студента обычно ведут 5-6 преподавателей. У студентов 4 курсов может быть от 3 до 5. И поэтому я хотел сделать следующий алгоритм:
1. Выбор количества преподов
2. Голосование (выбор препода из списка и оценки). Это все идет в ассоц.массив типа vote_teach[id][ocenka]
3. Записывается в базу данных
4. Админ смотрит на статистику.

Comment: Сейчас я встал на пункте 2. Как записать такой массив)

Comment: У меня ощущение, что вы сами запутались, да и мне все валеты перетасовали в голове )) Заходит сдутент 4-го курса. Для четвертого курса выводятся только те преподаватели, которые там могут вести (напр., пять). Пусть у данного лабуха ведут только три. Ну, так пусть этим трем и выставит оценки, а остальных не трогает. У них по умолчанию будет оценка NULL. Это будет означать, что у данного препода он не занимался, а пил пиво в это время.